# Remove duplicate row from SQL results

Tags: php, sql, oracle, duplicates

This is my SQL query to get result from `ORACLE` DB

```
SELECT U."UID", 
CONCAT(CONCAT(U.LNAME, ', '), U.FNAME) AS UNAME,
M.NAME,
(SELECT COUNT(LH."UID") FROM DRUPAL_SYS.LOGIN_HISTORY LH WHERE LH."UID"=U."UID" ) AS VIEWS_COUNT,
L.LOGIN as "ACCESS" FROM DRUPAL_SYS.USERS U INNER JOIN DRUPAL_SYS.LOGIN_HISTORY L ON L."UID" = U."UID"
INNER JOIN ABC_WEBAPP.MEMBER_USER_ROLE MUR ON MUR.USER_ID=U.MDES_ID AND MUR.MEMBER_ID LIKE '%' 
INNER JOIN ABC_WEBAPP.MEMBER M ON M.ID=MUR.MEMBER_ID WHERE U.LOGIN != 0 AND U."UID">1 ORDER BY L."LOGIN" ASC`
```

Its giving a result with duplicate `names`

[image]

But my expected result should be like

[image]

Comment: Just group your result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT U."UID", 
CONCAT(CONCAT(U.LNAME, ', '), U.FNAME) AS UNAME,
M.NAME,
(SELECT COUNT(LH."UID") FROM DRUPAL_SYS.LOGIN_HISTORY LH WHERE LH."UID"=U."UID" ) AS VIEWS_COUNT,
MAX(L.LOGIN) as "ACCESS" FROM DRUPAL_SYS.USERS U 
INNER JOIN DRUPAL_SYS.LOGIN_HISTORY L ON L."UID" = U."UID"
INNER JOIN ABC_WEBAPP.MEMBER_USER_ROLE MUR ON MUR.USER_ID=U.MDES_ID AND MUR.MEMBER_ID LIKE '%' 
INNER JOIN ABC_WEBAPP.MEMBER M ON M.ID=MUR.MEMBER_ID WHERE U.LOGIN != 0 AND U."UID">1
ORDER BY L."LOGIN" ASC`
GROUP BY UNAME, MNAME
```

changed `L.LOGIN` to `MAX(L.LOGIN)` and added `GROUP BY` clause

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT U."UID", 
CONCAT(CONCAT(U.LNAME, ', '), U.FNAME) AS UNAME,
M.NAME,
(SELECT COUNT(LH."UID") FROM DRUPAL_SYS.LOGIN_HISTORY LH WHERE LH."UID"=U."UID" ) AS VIEWS_COUNT,
L.LOGIN as "ACCESS" FROM DRUPAL_SYS.USERS U INNER JOIN DRUPAL_SYS.LOGIN_HISTORY L ON L."UID" = U."UID"
INNER JOIN ABC_WEBAPP.MEMBER_USER_ROLE MUR ON MUR.USER_ID=U.MDES_ID AND MUR.MEMBER_ID LIKE '%' 
INNER JOIN ABC_WEBAPP.MEMBER M ON M.ID=MUR.MEMBER_ID WHERE U.LOGIN != 0 AND U."UID">1 GROUP BY UNAME ORDER BY L."LOGIN" ASC`
```

Comment: ORA-00904: "UNAME": invalid identifier

Comment: change it to U.LNAME ,U.FNAME

Comment: Tried. But getting ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get one result row per `UID` and `UNAME`, you'd group by these fields.

```
GROUP BY UID, UNAME
```

Then for all remaining fields decide which value to show. E.g. you have four records for "2689 kaila, piyush", which name do you want to show? The first? The last? The maximum? ... Same for views count; the maximum? The sum? And again the same question for the access column.

Example:

```
select uid, uname, max(name), max(views_count), max(access)
from (<your query here>) query
group by uid, uname;
```

Copy and paste (ORDER BY clause removed):

```
select uid, uname, max(name), max(views_count), max(access)
from 
(
  SELECT U."UID", 
  CONCAT(CONCAT(U.LNAME, ', '), U.FNAME) AS UNAME,
  M.NAME,
  (SELECT COUNT(LH."UID") FROM DRUPAL_SYS.LOGIN_HISTORY LH WHERE LH."UID"=U."UID" ) AS VIEWS_COUNT,
  L.LOGIN as "ACCESS" FROM DRUPAL_SYS.USERS U INNER JOIN DRUPAL_SYS.LOGIN_HISTORY L ON L."UID" = U."UID"
  INNER JOIN ABC_WEBAPP.MEMBER_USER_ROLE MUR ON MUR.USER_ID=U.MDES_ID AND MUR.MEMBER_ID LIKE '%' 
  INNER JOIN ABC_WEBAPP.MEMBER M ON M.ID=MUR.MEMBER_ID WHERE U.LOGIN != 0 AND U."UID">1
) query
group by uid, uname;
```

Comment: Done. However, this is just an example. *You* must decide which values to show per UID and UNAME. (And I am pretty sure this query could be simplified. It very much depends on which values shall be shown. I just showed a way to use the current result and get one row per UID and UNAME from it.)

Comment: Thanks  Thorsten Kettner.. but one error  ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
Error at Line: 1 Column: 53